# Switching frames (in Arsenic) using an http request

Tags: python, selenium, http, webdriver

I've got a project in arsenic (async version of selenium) where I need to change the context to an iframe. Arsenic does not have the built-in switchTo functionality of Selenium, but I can send a custom request. I just can't figure out how to get it to work. Based off of [this documentation](https://www.w3.org/TR/webdriver/#dfn-switch-to-frame), it seems like I should be able to send something like this:

```
await driver.request(url="/session/{sessionID}/frame", method="POST")
```

Where sessionID is the session ID and frame is the id for the frame. Unsurprisingly, that doesn't work and I can't really find any instructions on how to use HTTP requests to change contexts since most applications for this have built-in switch_to functionality.

Answer (score 0):

You were very close. It turns out arsenic is creating a connection [prefixed](https://github.com/HENNGE/arsenic/blob/7323c550a46b94aa0dcda6659b9c3eff11bec3f0/src/arsenic/webdriver.py#L60) with `"/session/{session_id}"` already, so you just need to provide the last part of the URL path like this:

```py
await session.request(
    url="/frame",
    method="POST",
    data={"id": {"element-6066-11e4-a52e-4f735466cecf": iframe.id}},
)
```

... where `iframe` holds a reference to `Element`. You can retrieve it for example by waiting for it like this:

```py
consent_iframe = await session.wait_for_element(5, "#some-element-id")
```

To give more details: the `id` field has to be an object which [represents a web element](https://www.w3.org/TR/webdriver/#dfn-represents-a-web-element) according to the spec, which means having a constant `element-6066-11e4-a52e-4f735466cecf` as a key, and a [web element reference](https://www.w3.org/TR/webdriver/#dfn-web-element-reference) as a value.